# Custom filters and converters in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, jsf-2.2

Since PrimeFaces does not yet support converter for `<p:dataTable>` filters, I'm trying to implement my own custom filter for `<p:calendar>` (of course, the design of this filter still looks somewhat ugly. It needs to apply proper CSS that I cannot).

```
<p:column id="discountStartDate" sortBy="#{row.discountStartDate}" style="width:140px;">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Start Date<br/>

        <p:calendar id="startDateFilter" converter="#{dateTimeConverter}"
                    timeZone="Asia/Kolkata" locale="#{localeBean.locale}"
                    pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a" 
                    readonly="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}"
                    label="Start Date"
                    effect="slide" required="true"
                    size="12"
                    showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true">

            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{discountManagedBean.startDateListener}" 
                    onstart="PF('blockDataTableUIWidget').block()"
                    oncomplete="PF('blockDataTableUIWidget').unblock()"
                    update="dataTable"/>
        </p:calendar>

    </f:facet>

    <!--No need to refer to-->

    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.discountStartDate}" converter="#{dateTimeConverter}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:tooltip for="dataTableTxtDiscountStartDate" value="#{messages['tooptip.dataTable.popup.calendar']}"/>
            <p:calendar id="dataTableTxtDiscountStartDate" binding="#{edStartDate}" value="#{row.discountStartDate}" converter="#{dateTimeConverter}" timeZone="Asia/Kolkata" locale="#{localeBean.locale}" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a" readonly="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}" label="#{messages['discount.startdate']}" effect="explode" required="true" showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

When a date is selected from the calendar, the listener specified in `<p:ajax>` is invoked.

```
public void startDateListener(SelectEvent event)
{
    if(event.getObject() instanceof DateTime)
    {
        //org.joda.time.DateTime
        DateTime startDate=(DateTime) event.getObject();
        System.out.println(startDate+" : "+startDate.getZone().getID()+ " : "+startDate.getZone());
    }
}
```

The selected date is retrieved in this method but how can this date be used inside the `load()` method? `<p:dataTable>` uses `org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel<Discount>`.

Is there a way to use this date from this listener method so that the data table - `<p:dataTable>` can be updated after filtering the rows based on the date supplied through the calendar - `<p:calendar>`?

---

How can this date can be used in the overridden `load()` method?

```
@Override
public List<Discount> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, String> filters)
{
     //Do something with filters to add the date selected from the calendar of the given filter we are talking about.

     return discountService.getList(first, pageSize, multiSortMeta, filters);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a major enhancement in [data table filters](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml) in [PrimeFaces 5.0 final](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/primefaces/primefaces/5.0/) [released](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3132) on May 5, 2014.

> PrimeFaces DataTable Filtering has been a useful feature to quickly
>   filter data using ajax. However there were two main limitations; it
>   was only based on string comparison and no support for custom
>   filtering implementations. Thanks to a PrimeFaces PRO sponsorship,
>   filtering is greatly enhanced for PF5.
>
> **Filter Facets**
>
> Filtering elements were limited to an input text and a native
>   dropdown, **now if an input component is defined using filter facet, it
>   becomes the filter.** This enables customizable UIs, ajax update support
>   for filters, ***using objects*** instead of simple strings as filter values
>   and more.

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3084

For example,

```
<p:column id="id" headerText="#{messages['id']}" sortBy="#{row.discountId}" filterBy="#{row.discountId}" filterMatchMode="exact">
    <f:facet name="filter">
        <p:inputText onkeyup="PF('dataTableUIWidget').filter();" converter="javax.faces.Long" class="ui-column-filter"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{row.discountId}"/>
</p:column>
```

`discountId` would be converted to `Long` by the specified converter. `dataTableUIWidget` is a `widgetVar` of `<p:dataTable>`.

In case of `LazyDataModel<T>`, the type of the `Map` of filters has been changed to `Map<String, Object>` (from `Map<String, String>`)  both the overloaded versions of the `load()` method.

For single column sorting,

```
@Override
public List<Type> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
    return super.load(first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder, filters);
}
```

and for multiple columns sorting.

```
@Override
public List<Type> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, Object> filters) {
    return super.load(first, pageSize, multiSortMeta, sortOrder, filters);
}
```

As for the example in the question, it can be rewritten something like the following.

```
<p:column id="discountStartDate" headerText="#{messages['discount.startdate']}" filterBy="#{row.discountStartDate}" sortBy="#{row.discountStartDate}" width="200" style="text-align: right;">

    <f:facet name="filter">
        <p:calendar id="filterStartDate" converter="#{dateTimeConverter}"
                    timeZone="Asia/Kolkata" locale="#{localeBean.locale}"
                    pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
                    readonly="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}"
                    label="#{messages['discount.startdate']}"
                    effect="slide"
                    size="12"
                    onclick="PF('filterStartDateWidget').setDate(null);PF('dataTableUIWidget').filter();"
                    widgetVar="filterStartDateWidget"
                    showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true">

            <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
                    onstart="PF('dataTableUIWidget').filter();PF('blockDataTableUIWidget').block();"
                    oncomplete=" PF('blockDataTableUIWidget').unblock();"
                    onerror="alert('error');"/>
        </p:calendar>
    </f:facet>

    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.discountStartDate}" converter="#{dateTimeConverter}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:tooltip for="dataTableTxtDiscountStartDate" value="#{messages['tooptip.dataTable.popup.calendar']}"/>
            <p:calendar id="dataTableTxtDiscountStartDate" binding="#{edStartDate}" value="#{row.discountStartDate}" converter="#{dateTimeConverter}" timeZone="Asia/Kolkata" locale="#{localeBean.locale}" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a" readonly="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}" label="#{messages['discount.startdate']}" effect="explode" required="true" showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

`dateTimeConverter` is a type of `org.joda.time.DateTime`. Hence, the date passed through this filter will be available as `org.joda.time.DateTime` after just casting from `Object` taking it from the filter `Map`.