# How can I implement a custom column filter in icefaces using something like a checkbox?

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I'm currently using "filterBy" for filtering via inputText components and its working very well.  I'd like to be able to filter one of my columns with the selectBooleanCheckbox component.

It looks like this can be done in primefaces:

[Custom filters and converters in p:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180501/custom-filters-and-converters-in-pdatatable)

But I'm not quite sure how to do it in icefaces (if at all possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an ICEfaces developer himself, this is not possible.

http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/0/22736.page

As explained in the link, you can use the "filterOptions" attribute to use a h:selectOneMenu with selectItems as a filter, which works for me.